# How to show a modal window with *ngFor for multiple items in Angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am experimenting with a simple project in order to learn Angular and I have currently a problem: 
I am loading some dummy people with a service and then displaying boxes with the persons' names. And when I click on a box, a modal popup comes up and displays more info about this person - currently just a `string` of a short bio.

The problem is that I have an `*ngFor` to itterate over the `persons` and then what I suspect happens is that I also create a modal window for each and every one. Then the modal window does not know which is the currently selected person, so it just shows me the bio of the the first person from the list ...

So the question is how do I make it work for each currently selected person; i.e. when I click on person with id = 3, the modal displays the bio of that same person.

I guess this needs to be done programatically, that's why I am not using stuff like `href="#modal" data-toggle="modal"` to bind the modal window to an event.

Any better ideas?

Here is what I have: `PersonComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'person',
    templateUrl: './person.component.html'
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

    people: Person[];

    selectedPerson: Person;

    personBio: string;

    @ViewChild('personModal') private personModal;

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private stateService: StateService,
                private personService: PersonService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAllPeople();
    }

    private loadAllPeople() {

        this.personService.getPeople()
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.people = result;
            }, error => {
                this.console.log(error);
            });
    }

    goToPersonEditComponent(person: Person) {
        this.stateService.person = this.selectedPerson;
        this.router.navigate(['../' + FrontendRoute.EDIT], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
    }


    loadPersonBioModal(person: Person) {
        if (this.personModal) {
            this.selectedPerson = person;
            jQuery(this.personModal.nativeElement).modal('show');
        }

        this.personService.getPersonBio(person.id)
            .subscribe((bio) => this.personBio = bio);
    }

    closeModal() {
        if (this.personModal) {
            jQuery(this.personModal.nativeElement).on('hide.bs.modal', (evt) => {
                this.selectedPerson = null;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Person edit component: I am not showing the whole thing, to keep it simple, but the idea is that I get the selected person and from the id attribute I can edit it's bio.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'person-edit',
    templateUrl: './person-edit.component.html'
})

export class PersonEditComponent implements OnInit {

    person: Person;

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private packService: PackService,
                private orderService: PackOrderService,
                private stateService: StateService,
                private eventBusService: EventBusService,
                private loggingService: LoggingService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.person = this.stateService.person;
    }     

}
```

A simple service for passing stuff between components (I wanted it this way instead of with @Input):

```
@Injectable()
export class StateService {

    private _person: Person;

    constructor() {
    }

    get person() {
        return this._person;
    }

    set person(person: Person) {
        this._person = person;
    }

    clear() {
        this._person = null;
    }
}
```

And here is my template where I have the `modal`:

```
<div>
    <h2 class="h2">People</h2>
    <div class="item-collection item-collection-3-columns item-collection-tablet item-collection-wide">
        <div class="items">
            <article *ngFor="let person of people"
                     (click)="loadPersonBioModal(person)">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <span>{{person.name}}</span>
                        <span data-original-title="Show Person's Bio"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>

<div #personModal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" style="display: none;"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-has-header modal-has-footer">
        <div class="modal-content">{{personBio}}</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="section-btns">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
                        (click)="closeModal()">Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
                        (click)="goToPersonEditComponent(selectedPerson)">Edit Bio
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the PersonService, which makes a http call:

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    }

    getPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
        return this.http.get<Person[]>(BackendRoute.PERSON_DATA)
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(new Error('An unexpected error occurred' + error));
            });
    }

    getPersonBio(): Observable<Person> {
        return this.http.get<Person>(BackendRoute.PERSON_BIO)
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(new Error(error)));
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `PersonService` class as well?

Comment: @amal I added it at the bottom.

Comment: and where is the `getPersonBio()` method in it?

Comment: I edited the question i a hurry and didn't add it. Now it's here.

Comment: One more question. Are you assigning `this.personBio` to any value anywhere else in your `PersonComponent` class other than the subscription code of `getPersonBio()` within `loadPersonBioModal()`?

Comment: No, that's the only place. Basically I call the `loadPersonBioModal()` function whenever I click on a box with a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, given your comments, I think what's happening likely is you are showing your modal before the `getPersonBio()` returns the person information and assigns it to `personBio` property.

A likely easy way to tackle this would be to use the [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to asynchronously update the values for you. Try this,

in your PersonComponent,

```
personBio: Observable<Person>;

loadPersonBioModal(person: Person) {
  if (this.personModal) {
    this.selectedPerson = person;
    // directly assigning the returned observable of Person type and let async pipe do its magic in the template
    this.personBio = this.personService.getPersonBio(person.id);
    jQuery(this.personModal.nativeElement).modal('show');
  }
}
```

In your template,

```
<div class="modal-content">{{ personBio | async }}</div>
```

You have to import `CommonModule` for this to work as probably seen from the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). Also, using jQuery methods directly in angular is not recommended unless there is no other supported way of doing it.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I ended up doing something completely different, but in the end that worked! Thanks!